# Can you change legend style for bar datasets with chart.js?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm using chart.js 2.9.4

I have a combined line and bar graph. The line dataset uses diamonds ('rectrot') for the points.
In the legend, I wish the bar datasets to remain as the default rectangles but for the line dataset to use the diamond style.

```
options: {
    aspectRatio: 1.77778,
    legend: {
        display: chart.displayLegend,
        labels: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            boxWidth: 14,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fontColor: '#404040'
        },
        position: 'bottom'
    }
...
```

I have set **usePointStyle** to true, and this *does* set the legend to the diamond for my line dataset. However, the bar dataset legends have now become circles instead of rectangles. I have tried setting `pointStyle: 'rect'` for my bar datasets but this had no effect.

Is it possible to use **usePointStyle** for bar datasets or is this only for line datasets?
If so, is it possible to use a function to set the value of **usePointStyle** based on the type of the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only way to achieve this is by setting the pointstyle option in the legend options like this:

```
             options: {
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        labels: {
                            usePointStyle: false,
                            pointStyle: 'cross',
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
```

The downside of this is that it will count for all datasets.

I have put in a pull request at chart.js to allow the posibility to give a pointStyle in the barChart dataset configuration so you can have multiple styles.

Github issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/8341